# Access from container to host

Tags: docker

I have a elasticsearch service in my host.

I can run in my console:

```
$ curl http://127.0.0.1:9200
{
  "name" : "node00",
  "cluster_name" : "cluster00",
  "cluster_uuid" : "Zk4RzStrTLeSD2TQXReRlA",
  "version" : {
    "number" : "5.0.0",
    "build_hash" : "253032b",
    "build_date" : "2016-10-26T04:37:51.531Z",
    "build_snapshot" : false,
    "lucene_version" : "6.2.0"
  },
  "tagline" : "You Know, for Search"
}
```

I got my ip address for the docker comunication:

```
$ sudo ifconfig
docker0   Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 02:42:6b:fc:f8:82  
          inet addr:172.17.0.1  Bcast:0.0.0.0  Mask:255.255.0.0
```

Inside container:

```
root@1e473bd5ca92:~# curl http://172.17.0.1:9200
curl: (7) Failed to connect to 172.17.0.1 port 9200: Connection refused
```

But if I run this query to internet, I got a valid response:

```
root@1e473bd5ca92:~# curl 'https://api.ipify.org?format=json'
{"ip":"192.143.241.250"}
```

How I can access from container to the elasticsearch service from host?

Answer (score 0):

It is likely that the Elasticsearch instance on your host is only listening on `localhost` (127.0.0.1).  Take a look at the `network.host` setting in your main configuration file (possibly `/etc/elasticsearch/elasticsearch.yml`, or something similar).  If it looks something like:

```
network.host:
   - 127.0.0.1
```

You can explicitly add the Docker bridge interface:

```
network.host:
  - 127.0.0.1
  - 172.17.0.1
```

Or you could have it listen on all interfaces (if you are certain that's the behavior you want):

```
network.host:
  - 0.0.0.0
```

([reference for this configuration setting](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-network.html))